# how to get html5 video total duration displayed without playing the video

Tags: html, video, codeigniter-3, using, duration

I do found something online that is just about to be similar to what am trying to achieve, but here are a few problems i encountered. (1) i want the time be in minutes and seconds format. (2) the code only works for a single video in my html file. how can i make the code work for multiple videos in my file all showing their different durations. below is the code

```js
<script> var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('video_player'), meta = document.getElementById('meta'); myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () { var duration = myVideoPlayer.duration; meta.innerHTML = "Duration is " + duration.toFixed(2) + " seconds." }); </script>
```

```html
<video id="video_player" width="320" height="240" controls poster="something/something.jpg"> <source src="someVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>

<div id="meta"></div>
```

This is what I want to achieve using codeigniter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" id = "myVideo" controls>
  <source src="someVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>
var e = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var cancelAlert = false;
var run = function() {
if (e.readyState === 4 && !cancelAlert) {//readyState 4 means it is loaded fully
cancelAlert = true;//This is so that it only alerts once. No spam pls.
alert(e.duration);
}
requestAnimationFrame(run);//This is so that it runs every frame.
};
run();//run the function
</script>
```

You may need to do some tweaking, and there is probably a more efficient way to do this, but this is what I do.

Comment: Hi Vakore, it's actually not working as intented, At first it's alerting 'NaN' , and then when you click OK, it only shows you the regular player with no any effect of hiding the controls then only showing the video duration " just like in the picture above, that's what i want to achieve".

Comment: it really doesnt work. are there any external .js links to add or css styling to make it works? i would really appreciate you going through everything

Comment: I updated my answer. The reason why it returned 'NaN' was because the video hadn't loaded yet.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but clearly not what am looking for. Anyway i do found something online that is just  about to be similar to what am trying to achieve, but here are the problems i encountered. hopely you can help me with it.(1) i want the time be in minute and seconds format. (2) the code only works for just one video in a file. how can i make the code work for every multiple videos in my file all showing their different durations. below is the code

Comment: <video id="video_player" width="320" height="240" controls  poster="something/something.jpg">
   <source src="someVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="meta"></div>

<script>
var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('video_player'),
    meta = document.getElementById('meta');

myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
    var duration = myVideoPlayer.duration;
    meta.innerHTML = "Duration is " + duration.toFixed(2) + " seconds."
});
</script>

Comment: Can you please update your question instead? Thank you!